# ng-style not updating width and height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

i'm trying to create some circles that auto resize. the problem is that the ng-style attribute isn't updating the styles. http://plnkr.co/edit/3HxSzWIyUsLUW6UwFlRR see plunker

Javascript :

```
$scope.sellingPoints = {
    '1':{ 'text':'Newest Technologies'},
    '2':{ 'text':'Rapid Development'},
    '3':{ 'text':'Scaleable Solutions'},
    '4':{ 'text':'Custom CMS'}  
};

$scope.kpi = {};
$scope.sizes = {};
$scope.onResize = function() {
    console.log('joe');
    var kpifit = document.getElementById('fit');
    $scope.sizes.width = kpifit.offsetWidth - 30;
    $scope.kpi.width = $scope.sizes.width + 'px';
    $scope.kpi.height = $scope.sizes.width + 'px';  
    console.log($scope.sizes.width);
} 

angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
    $scope.onResize();
})
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.onResize();
}, 300);
```

html :

```
<div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" id="fit" ng-repeat="item in sellingPoints">
        <div class="kpi" ng-style="{'width':kpi.width,'height':kpi.height}">
            <div class="kpi-text">{{item.text}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this code inside a directive? Or inside a normal page? If it's in a page, I think you should call controllerName.kpi.width or something in that order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handlers bound with `angular.element.prototype.bind` (and `on`) methods don't trigger digest by itself. So you need to do it manually:

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
    $scope.onResize();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/dPphd7KkQC7jNqleEgHb?p=info

Answer (score 0):

If you want width value in `ng-style` using function

This below example is use for progress bar chart.

```
$scope.ChartDataList = [{
        Ch_Name: 'Document',
        Ch_Percentage: '40%',
        getMaxLength() {
            return '40%';
        }
    }, {
        Ch_Name: 'Video/Audio',
        Ch_Percentage: '66%',
        getMaxLength() {
            return '66%';
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.